# Generating type #ref for List<> response in Spring Boot OpenAPI

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, spring-annotations

I was asked to generate the following OpenAPI definition in the Spring Boot:

```json
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "Successful operation",
    "content": {
      "application/json": {
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Entities"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
...
"components": {
  "schemas": {
    "Entities": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "Some description",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Entity"
      }
    },
    "Entity": {
      "type": "object",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The type returned by a controller is `List<Entity>`, so it is the JSON array with no surrounding object:

```json
[{}, {}, {}]
```

How can I make it? Is it possible to generate it using the annotations only?

I was trying to achieve it with the following annotation:

```java
@PostMapping("/entities")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful operation", content = {
       @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(name = "Entities",
                                                      description = "Some description",
                                                      implementation = Entity.class)))
    })
public List<Entity> getEntities() { ... }
```

but what I get is the direct Entity #ref in the *responses* block, without the `Entities` scheme and "*Some description*":

```json
responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "Successful operation",
    "content": {
      "application/json": {
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Entity"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
...
"components": {
  "schemas": {
    "Entity": {
      "type": "object",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```